# How to give each instanced object a unique selection value so that each instance in the system is different than the previous?

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances

[image]
[image]

Here I've instanced 100 tiny 10x10 grids into a larger, second 10x10 grid.

My goal is to have each instance of the tiny grid to have one less square instanced than the previous grid.

So for example, the grid labeled as 1 in the bottom left hand corner would have a full 100 grid of squares. but 2 grid would have 99, 3 grid would have 98 and so on.

You can see in the node tree theres a "greater than" compare node attached to the selection socket in the first instance on points. Obviously by lowering that value every tiny grid subtracts squares from their array equally.

[image]

Is there a way to make each instance subtract an incremental value of squares from their array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use *[Capture attribute](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/attribute/capture_attribute.html)* node for that.

[image]

But keep in mind that you have to choose correct domain for them

Comment: Thank you! This gave me almost exactly what i needed.